# How to create redirect rules?

Tags: regex, lighttpd

How do I create a rule in lighttpd that redirects all URLs of this type: `http://<ip>/dr` to port 443. And everything else, that doesn't end in `.png`, to port 5480.

The script below works in a rather interesting way:

`http://<ip>/dr` is redirected to `5480`

`http://<ip>//dr` is redirected to `443/dr`

`http://<ip>/png` is redirected to `443/dr`

`http://<ip>/qwerty` is redirected to `5480`

`http://<ip>/qwerty.png` is not redirected

```
$SERVER["socket"] == ":80" {
    server.use-ipv6 = "enable"
    server.document-root = "..."
    $HTTP["host"] =~ "^(.+)$" {
        url.redirect = ( ".\*dr$" => "https://%1:443/dr",
                         "(?<!\.png)$" => "https://%1:5480/" )
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the regexes were fine, but the browser caching tripped us. Everything worked in Incognito window.